# Apply custom styles to angular ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid

I am using ng-grid(UI-grid) in my angular project.
My client gave me tabled grid as mockup. Now I want to design UI-grid as per the clients design.

Please suggest me the way how can I achieve this.

Comment: Use CSS! Really, that's your whole question? Don't you think it would be helpful if you included at least something like a screenshot in your question?

Comment: Here is design client is expecting to apply to ui.grid.
Screenshot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x44jb7nvww8t1yq/Screen%20Shot%201936-07-12%20at%206.47.57%20pm.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to add image to ng-grid. You have to use cellTemplate, the content of this can be stored into a separate *.html file as well...

```
// main.js
```

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

```
$http.post('/MyPage/index.json?details=full').success(function (data) {
    $scope.carData = data;
});

$scope.updatecar =function(row){
   $http.post('/MyPage/index.json?details=&carID='+row.getProperty('carID')+'&enable='+row.getProperty('link')).success(function (data) {          
    $scope.carData = data;
});     
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'carData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'carName', displayName: 'car Name'},
        {field: 'carTemperature', displayName: 'Temperature'
            , cellTemplate: 
                    '<div ng-class="ngCellText">' +
                    '{{row.getProperty(col.field)}} <img ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'imageName\')}}" alt=""/>'+                        
                    '  <a href ="" ng-click="updatecar(row)">' +
                    '{{row.getProperty(\'linkText\')}} </a>' +
                    '</div>'
        }
    ]
};
```

});